# Attribute constraints - Enum of various base type in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, types, enums, xsd, attributes

I want to set an attribute with an enumeration of values from different types like (int, range of float, boolean). Do you know how do that ? Thks.

i.e.:
type : TypeType
value1 (int)
Value2(float in range[0.001 to 100]
Value3 (boolean true or false)

[screenshot of eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0n0m.png)

Comment: What design tool is that? Eclipse is a very big product you need to be more specific about which part you are using.

Comment: It's the plugin XML.

Comment: That doesn't look anything like the plugin.xml editor

Comment: The name of plugin is XML.

Comment: Sorry but that means nothing to me. Where did it come from? Tell us more details about exactly what you are doing.

Comment: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-xml-editors-and-tools-0

Comment: That package contains numerous editors. Tell us exactly what you are doing/editing. We can't help with such vague descriptions.

Comment: I'm editing an xsd schema, I'd like to add an attribute to an element. This one must be restrict to  a set of values from types boolean and float.